# How to make a multi search for GUI in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a multi search that when i choose a selection value from a combo box, it will search the corresponding value. Here is my code:

```
search = Tk()
search.title("Search")
search.geometry("300x300")

drop = ttk.Combobox(search, value=["Search by...", "Book ID", "Book Name", "Author 
Name", "Genre"])
drop.current(0)
drop.place(x=300, y=10)
def search_info(): 
    global id_entry
    global book_name_entry
    global author_name_entry
    global genre_entry      
    global myresult

    id_get = id_entry.get()
    book_name_get = book_name_entry.get()
    author_name_get = author_name_entry.get()
    genre_get = genre_entry.get()

    selected = drop.get()
    sql = ""
    if selected == ["Search by..."]:
        test = Label(search, text="Tf u want to search?")
        test.place(x=300, y=70)
    if selected == ["Book ID"]:
        sql = "SELECT id,book_name,author_name,genre,price FROM books where id = '" + 
        id_get + "'"
    if selected == ["Book Name"]:
        sql = "SELECT id,book_name,author_name,genre,price FROM books where book_name = 
        '" + book_name_get + "'"
    if selected == ["Author Name"]:
        sql = "SELECT id,book_name,author_name,genre,price FROM books where author_name 
        = '" + author_name_get + "'"
    if selected == ["Genre"]:
        sql = "SELECT id,book_name,author_name,genre,price FROM books where genre = '" + 
        genre_get + "'"  
    mysqldb = mysql.connector.connect(host="Localhost", user="root",password="12345678", 
    database="bookstore")
    mycursor = mysqldb.cursor()
    records = mycursor.execute(sql)
    records = mycursor.fetchall()
    print(records)
    for i, (id1,book_name1,author_name1, genre1,price1) in enumerate(records,start=1):
        listBox.insert("", "end", values=(id1,book_name1,author_name1, genre1,price1))
        mysqldb.close()

Label(search, text="Search").place(x=10, y=10)
Button(search, text="Search", command=search_info ,height = 1, width = 13).place(x=140, 
y=40)
sql = Entry(search)
sql.place(x=140, y=10)
cols = ('id', 'book_name', 'author_name','genre','price')
listBox = ttk.Treeview(search, columns=cols, show='headings' )
for col in cols:
   listBox.heading(col, text=col)
   listBox.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
   listBox.place(x=10, y=200)

search.mainloop()
```

But when i try, it show that: NameError: name 'id_entry' is not defined
Now i still sticky with this problem so i hope someone can help me to fix  problem

Comment: First you need to define variables a = 5, and then if you want to change their values in a function, then use global a.

Comment: The code you posted does not ever create anything named `id_entry`, which would explain why you get the error `id_entry is not defined`.